# confused about uicontrol's nextresponder

Tags: ios, first-responder

If you add a UIView as a subview of the UIViewControler's view and do not add events to the UIView. UIViewControler's method like  will be invoked. But if you add a UIView as a UIButton's subview and do not add events to the UIView, the button click event will not be invoked.So it confused me. It also happened when you add a button as a subview of a UIView, button didn't add target-action method, it's superview(UIView) didn't invoke method like  either.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that your **question** goes like this: Why does the taps on `UIButton` won't let `UIViewController` view's `touchesBegan` method invoked?

Let's take a look at this experimental project, I used frames instead of constraints for simplicity.

```
import UIKit

class MyButton: UIButton {
    override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
        super.touchesBegan(touches, with: event)
        print("BUTTON TOUCHES BEGAN")
    }
}

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()


        self.view.backgroundColor = .white

        let view1 = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 100, y: 100, width: 100, height: 100))
        view1.backgroundColor = .black
        self.view.addSubview(view1)

        let button = MyButton(type: .custom)
        button.frame = CGRect(x: 200, y: 100, width: 100, height: 100)
        button.setTitle("XXX", for: .normal)
        button.backgroundColor = .yellow
        button.setTitleColor(.black, for: .normal)
        button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(buttonClicked), for: .touchUpInside)
        self.view.addSubview(button)

        let view2 = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 50, height: 50))
        view2.backgroundColor = .red
        button.addSubview(view2)

    }

    @objc func buttonClicked() {
        print("buttonClccked")
    }

    override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
        super.touchesBegan(touches, with: event)

        print("TOUCHES BEGAN")
    }
}
```

I did each and every cases you mentioned.

The `view1` is a normal view. Adding it as a subview of the controller's view, and tapping on it triggers the `touchesBegan` in the controller. Which is fine.

The `view2` is added as a subview of a button, taking or not the button's whole frame, and you tap on the `view2`, the `touchesBegan` of the button is being triggered instead the controller's. Adding

These things happen because when you tap on the button, the tapping of the button takes precedence instead of the controller's view, because every touches that start from the button are counted as taps.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It helps me a lot.

Comment: Happy to help, and welcome to Stack Overflow. If this answer or any other one solved your issue, please mark it as accepted ;)